# How can I build Angular application without adding some components or modules?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I´m using Angular 9 to build an application with many modules and components modularized. When I will building this application, I need to exclude one module or component that compilation. I say module or components because I don´t know what is the best way to exclude this functionality that compilation.

**For example:**

I have two components. 
 `comp1.component.ts` contains three buttons:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {

  title = 'Loaded Component 1.';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

`comp2.component.ts` contains two buttons:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {

  title = 'Loaded Component 2.';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And the `.html` is the same for both:

```html
<p>{{title}}</p>
```

By other way, I have another component, where I want load one of these two components, depending on the environment where I load.

In the **environment A**, I need load `comp1.component.ts` and in the **environment B**, I need load `comp2.component.ts`. But if I load one of these components, the other component should not included in the build of this application but I don't have any idea to solve this....

Any idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks for watching.

Answer (score 2):

you can do the same as `environment` file is changed between build targets

```
"configurations": {
  "target-with-component2": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "path/to/comp1.component.ts",
        "with": "path/to/comp2.component.ts"
      }
    ],
```

it will replace components just as required in the question

Answer (score 2):

if you use **angular-cli** build project, you can modify **tsconfig.app.json** file add same configuration in root element

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/xxx/xxxxx/**/*"
  ]
}
```